# PHP redirect to specific url based on form submission with multiple sets of radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit

I am trying to set up a form that users of my website - piciscan.co.uk - will use to order photobooks. I would like to offer them some options when ordering their photobooks, and on submission of the form, I would like the customer to be redirected to the relevant page of my separate, shop website - piciscanshop.co.uk.

For example, should the user want to order a portrait photobook, in layout 4, with printed page numbers, they should be redirected to piciscanshop.co.uk/portrait-layout4-pagenums-photobook.

So far, I have the html for a form, and believe that it is possible, with some php, to make what I am looking for, happen.

Here is the html code:

```
<form id="layoutSelector" method="get" action="layoutSelector.php">

<fieldset>
<input type="radio" name="aspect" id="layoutAspectPortrait" value="portrait">
<label for="layoutAspectPortrait">Portrait</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="aspect" id="layoutAspectPortrait" value="landscape" checked="checked">
<label for="layoutAspectPortrait">Landscape</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<input type="radio" name="layout" id="layoutNumber1" value="layout1">
<label for="layoutNumber1">Layout 1</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="layout" id="layoutNumber2" value="layout2">
<label for="layoutNumber2">Layout 2</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="layout" id="layoutNumber3" value="layout3" checked="checked">
<label for="layoutNumber3">Layout 3</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="layout" id="layoutNumber4" value="layout4">
<label for="layoutNumber4">Layout 4</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<input type="radio" name="pageNums" id="layoutPageNums" value="pageNums">
<label for="layoutPageNums">Page Numbers</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="pageNums" id="layoutNoPageNums" value="" checked="checked">
<label for="layoutNoPageNums">No page numbers</label>
<br>
</fieldset>
<div class="submitsAndHiddens">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

So, I guess what I am looking for help with is: how to write layoutSelector.php.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layoutSelector.php, get the form data via `$_GET['field_name_here']`, process it however you want (use `var_dump($_GET);` to see everything that was passed in). Then, redirect to the appropriate page using `die(header('Location: other_page.php'));`.

So for your example in your question, layoutSelector.php might look something like this:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['layout'] === 'layout4' && $_GET['pageNums'] === 'layoutPageNums') {
        die(header('Location: /portrait-layout4-pagenums-photobook'));
    }
?>
```

Or, if all your pages are laid out this way, you could probably just do something like this:

```
<?php
    die(header('Location: /'. $_GET['aspect'] .'-'. $_GET['layout'] .'-'. $_GET['pageNums'] .'-photobook'));
?>
```

---

An even better solution would be to check these values via JavaScript when the form is submitted and change the form action, so no redirecting is needed (which would be faster).

Comment: Hi, Travesty3. Your second answer, with the die(header in, worked a treat. Marvellous!!

Answer (score 0):

in layoutSelector.php put this code

```
$page = $_GET['aspect'] . "-" . $_GET['layout'] . '-' . $_GET['pageNums'] . '-' .'photobook';


header('Location : '. 'http://piciscanshop.co.uk/'.$page);
```